c++ initializer list for custom classes working abnormally
Can anyone please help me understand what is wrong with the below code?
I am using C++20
I am initializing the vector of vector of class 'Interval', but it's getting initialized to 0s.
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Interval {
public:
    int start;
    int end;

    Interval() {}

    Interval(int _start, int _end) {
        start = _start;
        end = _end;
    }
};

vector<Interval> solve(vector<vector<Interval>> schedule) {
    vector<Interval> allSchedule;

    for(auto it : schedule) {
        for(auto it1 : it) {
            allSchedule.push_back(it1);
        }
    }

    auto comparator = [](Interval a, Interval b) {
        return a.start > b.start;
    };
    sort(allSchedule.begin(), allSchedule.end(), comparator);

    return allSchedule;
}

int main() {
    vector<vector<Interval>> schedule;
    schedule.push_back({new Interval(1,2), new Interval(5,6)});
    schedule.push_back({new Interval(1,3), new Interval(4,10)});
    vector<Interval> allSchedules = solve(schedule);
    for(auto it : allSchedules) {
        cout << it.start << " -> " << it.end << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

Getting the below output ( Unexpected )
1 -> 2
1 -> 3
0 -> 0
0 -> 0


And what do you expect?

Can't replicate your result. I get fatal error: 'bits/stdc++.h' file not found.

{new Interval(1,2), new Interval(5,6)} - here you invoke std::vector(begin, end) constructor that results in undefined behavior, because new Interval(1,2), new Interval(5,6) are not an array's begin and end. You seem to have Java or C# background. vector<Interval>  is not a vector of pointers and you don't need new.

Obligatory don't risk shooting yourself in the foot with #include <bits/stdc++.h> post.

Useful tool: Sanitizers Here is your code compiled with a good amount of warnings and basic sanitizers enabled: https://godbolt.org/z/fxWWrj91P . The warnings can't catch this problem, but the address sanitizer figures out you haven't really used iterators pretty fast when it spots the program marching out of valid memory. Figuring out what ACTUALLY happened in this case is requires experience you'll pick up over the next few months (and years).

vector<vector<Interval>> schedule;
schedule.push_back({new Interval(1,2), new Interval(5,6)});

that's a very weird bug, because vector has a constructor that can be used to initialize it from two pointers (iterators) to other container, for example:
Interval intervals[2];
vector<vector<Interval>> schedule;
schedule.push_back(std::vector<Interval>{ &(intervals[0]), &(intervals[2])});

but for this to work correctly, you need both pointers to point to the start and end of an array, in your case both pointers returned by operator new don't point to the same container, so this is undefined behavior, and address santizer marks this as buffer overflow.
with that said, you shouldn't be using operator new to create objects when aggregate initializing the vector, so the correct syntax is as follows.
vector<vector<Interval>> schedule;
schedule.push_back({Interval(1,2), Interval(5,6)});
schedule.push_back({Interval(1,3), Interval(4,10)});


{new Interval(1,2), new Interval(5,6)} - here you invoke std::vector(const Interval* begin, const Interval* end) constructor that results in undefined behavior, because new Interval(1,2), new Interval(5,6) are not an array's begin and end.
You seem to have Java or C# background: vector<Interval>  is not a vector of pointers and you don't need new.
Replace
schedule.push_back({new Interval(1,2), new Interval(5,6)});
schedule.push_back({new Interval(1,3), new Interval(4,10)});

with
schedule.push_back({{1, 2}, {5, 6}});
schedule.push_back({{1, 3}, {4, 10}});
//    inner vector ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
//inner vec elements^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^ - intervals

The output:
5 -> 6
4 -> 10
1 -> 2
1 -> 3


Interval can be an aggregate, it does not need user defined Interval() and Interval(int, int) constructors.
class Interval {
 public:
  int start;
  int end;
};


It's better if solve and comparator get their arguments by const references (one more example of your possible Java or C# backround).
vector<Interval> solve(const vector<vector<Interval>>& schedule);
auto comparator = [](const Interval& a, const Interval& b)

